# Angular 5 : conbination of multiple observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have an array on Observable, and I'd like to get one unique Observable which will return true if all the observables of my array will return true.

I tried this, but does not seem to work:

```js
const t = [Observable.of(true), Observable.of(false)];
let obs = Observable.of(true);
t.forEach(o => obs = obs.concat(o));

const obsResult = obs.pipe(
  takeWhile(val => val !== false), 
  reduce((acc, val) => acc && val)
);
obsResult.subscribe(r => console.log('result', r));
```

`t[1]` is false so I expect obsResult to send `false`, but instead I get `true`

Answer (score 0):

To work purely in streams:

1. Create a function that uses [`.from`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html) to wrap the array of observables into a new stream.
2. [`.concatAll()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)  that new stream to unwrap the inner observables (the observables in the array).
3. Then use [`.every`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/all.html)  which takes a predicate function to test the values of then unwrapped observables.

You'll now have a function that returns an observable that will emit `true/false` values based on the aggregate value of the array of observables.

```js
console.clear();
const obsSetF = [Rx.Observable.of(true), Rx.Observable.of(false)];
const obsSetT = [Rx.Observable.of(true), Rx.Observable.of(true)];

function allTrue(obsSet) {
  return Rx.Observable
    .from(obsSet)
    .concatAll()
    .every(a => a === true)
}

allTrue(obsSetF).subscribe(console.log);
allTrue(obsSetT).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.3/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest):

This will emit values using the latest values emitted by the passed in observables. Here's a good visualization of how it works: [combineLatest RxMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest)

In this case particularly though, it would be better not pass in a project function, since you just want to do a logical and of multiple observables.

The static version of `Observable.combineLatest` can take in an array of observables and emits their values as an array.

**Here's an example**:

```js
console.clear();
const tf = [Rx.Observable.of(true), Rx.Observable.of(false)];
const tt = [Rx.Observable.of(true), Rx.Observable.of(true)];

const obsResult =
  // if no projection function is passed to combineLatest
  // then it will emit an array of the latest values from the provided
  // observables in this case [true, false]
  Rx.Observable.combineLatest(tf)
    // map the output of this observable and perform a reduce to and
    // every value in the array
    .map((xs) => xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc && x));
obsResult.subscribe(r => console.log('result', r));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```